# Can you embed Python into a C program and then call it from C#/ASP.NET with no outside tools?

Tags: c#, python, c

I got a question about embedding Python into C/C++ programs.  I'm new to .NET and C sharp, and

I was recently able to call a few dlls (one simple hello world C I made from scratch with the help of Vladimir Tskhvaradze's 05 how to, and a user.32 out of the 70-536 book).

I see in my Python documentation 2.6 that I can embed Python into C/C++.

Is it possible to then call this newly created C program("module"?) with the Python embedded (code and Im assuming interpreter) from ASP.NET/C sharp and have it all coexist peacefully in .NET?

I see different tools etc...but I wanna know straight out the box can I do this.  Also how much would using Visual Studio C++ 08 or 10 help/hinder this process?

Comment: Hwo about IronPython instead?

Comment: @CDUB: I recommend sorting out the first question, and then asking the second with context afterwards. You stand a better chance of getting useful answers.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend to use COM: write a [COM server](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.4/pywin32/html/com/win32com/HTML/QuickStartServerCom.html) in Python (using win32com), and then access it from C# (using .NET's COM interop). You should start with a hello-world style application, to make sure it can work at all. This should not require any additional tools, and no C code.

Comment: There's a good book that describes this technique in detail, "Python Programming on Win32": http://oreilly.com/catalog/9781565926219/